# Invalid http response, which code to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I have a servlet that stores cards to a database. In js I use an jquery ajax request to get the cards from the servlet that gets them from the Database. If they haven't yet added any cards I just want to alert them and do nothing else. So, if the card coming from the db is null then I wanted to send a response using a different http code to instruct js to do the alert. If I use an error code the browser shows the error, I tried using method not accepted 405. But simple success codes are 'invalid' according to chrome, I tried 100 continue.

```
            if(nextCard == null){
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONTINUE);
                //send back empty list error...
                response.getWriter().write("user hasn't added any cards yet");
                return;
            }
```

ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
      type:"get",
      url:"QuestionPage",
      data:{name:"next",result:result},
      success: function(response,status) {
          if(status == 100){
              alert('You havent added any cards yet, these waters are calm... go chum the water and come back when they start to circle.');
              return;
          }
          cardReievedUpdateUI(response);
      }
   });
```

I also tried this:

```
$.ajax({
          type:"get",
          url:"QuestionPage",
          data:{name:"next",result:result},
          success: function(response,status) {
              cardReievedUpdateUI(response);
          },
          statusCode: {
              100: function(){
                     alert('You havent added any cards yet, these waters are calm... go chum the water and come back when they start to circle.');
              }
           }
       });
```

This is the one that made the browser show an error, I am just trying to tell myself what to do..

this is my error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

How should I do this?

screenshot of error: [image]

Comment: `simple success codes are 'invalid' according to chrome` Huh? HTTP status codes work fine.

Comment: I would say a 200 should work fine for this request.  Rather than returning null, return an empty array.  Optionally a 204 (No Content) could work as well.

Comment: 204 worked. That's strange.